# CLI range arguments convention

Tags: node.js, arguments, range, command-line-interface

I want to write a command line tool with Node and I need to parse a list of range parameters. My first thought was to represent with two numbers with colon separation:

```
script 1:4 2:3 1:8
```

or

```
script --balls=1:4 --period=2:3 --height=1:8
```

But I want to know if there is a convention for it. I'm reading a [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist) and [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) documentation but I find nothing about this.

Do you know if there is a convention on this?

Answer (score 1):

With [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander), you can use the [range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander#coercion) option. Example from the docs:

```
function range(val) {
  return val.split('..').map(Number);
}

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .usage('[options] <file ...>')
  .option('-r, --range <a>..<b>', 'A range', range)
  .parse(process.argv);
```